# How to compare two lists in Python using for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am doing an exercise that ask me the following tasks. I am stack in the third one:

1. Create two variables called gandalf and saruman and assign them the spell power lists. Create a variable called spells to store the number of spells that the sorcerers cast.

   ```
   spells = 10
   gandalf = [10, 11, 13, 30, 22, 11, 10, 33, 22, 22]
   saruman = [23, 66, 12, 43, 12, 10, 44, 23, 12, 17]
   ```
2. Create two variables called gandalf_wins and saruman_wins. Set both of them to 0.
   You will use these variables to count the number of clashes each sorcerer wins.

   ```
   gandalf_wins=0
   saruman_wins=0
   ```
3. Using the lists of spells of both sorcerers, update variables gandalf_wins and saruman_wins to count the number of times each sorcerer wins a clash.

My solution is that but is not comparing all the elements of the list, could you help me?

```
for spells in saruman, gandalf:
    if gandalf>saruman:
        gandalf_wins += 1
    elif saruman>gandalf:
        saruman_wins += 1

print("Total gandalf wins:", gandalf_wins)
print("Total saruman wins:", saruman_wins)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way your for loop is defined. You should iterate over the elements in the lists and then compare them.

```
for s, g in zip(saruman, gandalf):
    if g>s:
        gandalf_wins += 1
    elif s>g:
        saruman_wins += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to create pairs of the spells, so can easily compare them:

```
gandalf_wins=0
saruman_wins=0

gandalf = [10, 11, 13, 30, 22, 11, 10, 33, 22, 22]
saruman = [23, 66, 12, 43, 12, 10, 44, 23, 12, 17]

for spells in zip(saruman, gandalf):
    # iterations look like: [(10, 23), (11, 66), (13, 12)...]
    gandalf_spell_power = spells[0]
    saruman_spell_power = spells[1]

    if gandalf_spell_power>saruman_spell_power:
        gandalf_wins += 1
    elif saruman_spell_power>gandalf_spell_power:
        saruman_wins += 1

print("Total gandalf wins:", gandalf_wins)
print("Total saruman wins:", saruman_wins)
```

Output:

```
('Total gandalf wins:', 4)
('Total saruman wins:', 6)
```

Comment: tip: use " for gandalf_spell_power, saruman_spell_power in zip ...." to unpack the zip directly.